# C# Textbox checking

Tags: c#

Am trying to test if the content of my `textBox` is equal to zero, I have two `textBox` with the same values. I want to ensure that the user cannot continue  except one of my `textBox` is equal to zero. tried some means but not working. i tried this:

```
double amount;
amount = double.Parse(transactDisplay.Text.ToString());
if (amount > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please pay before proceding", "Money not paid",
                                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);

}
```

but its not working.

Comment: In what format is the text in `transactDisplay` text box?

Comment: Why is not working?? you receive and error?

Comment: amount = ConvertToDouble(transactDsiplay.Text)... but it sounds like transactDisplay should be a numericupdown rather than a text box? Also if this is for money you should consider using decimal rather than double

Comment: OT, but change from `double` to `decimal` .

Answer (score 3):

The Text property of a Textbox return a string, so you have to ensure that it's a number and try to convert it. You can use something like this:

```
double amount;
if (double.TryParse(transactDisplay.Text.Trim(), out amount) && amount <= 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please pay before proceding", "Money not paid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
    return;
}
else 
{
   MessageBox.Show("Please add amount greater than 0.", "Money not paid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
   return;
}
```

If the convertion didn't pass, the second condition (amount <= 0) will not be tested.

Comment: You can use the same if: if (double.TryParse(transactDisplay.Text.Trim(), out amount) && amount ==0) (because if the first condition didn't succed, it won't try the second one)

Comment: `amount == 0` should be `amount > 0` so that negative values won't be allowed.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I will correct the awser.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to work with numbers only, you should use NumericUpDown controls which will ensure that the user will not be able to type letters by mistake. NumericUpDown controls also have a *DecimalPlaces* property so they fit to most scenarios.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ValueNotZero(numericUpDown1) && ValueNotZero(numericUpDown2))
        MessageBox.Show("You forgot to pay!");
    else if (!ValueNotZero(numericUpDown1) && !ValueNotZero(numericUpDown2))
        MessageBox.Show("One of the values must not be Zero!");
}

private bool ValueNotZero(NumericUpDown numericControl)
{
    return (double)numericControl.Value > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the validating event which is design to let you test the value of a control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx

You can also show errors message using ErrorProvider : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/95ysxkwy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
double amount = double.Parse(transactDisplay.Text); 
if (amount != 0) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("Please pay before proceding", "Money not paid", 
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop); 
}
```

If it's not equal to zero, flag the message.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
double amount;
if (double.TryParse(transactDisplay.Text, out amount) && amount > 0) {
    MessageBox.Show("Please pay before proceding", "Money not paid",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
}
```